# Find the count of "date" appearing in a string using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a string that contain dates many times.

for example

> 2016-01-23 AKS Could you please check 2015-11-23 AKS Could you please check .2015-10-06 RM I added the remarks 2015-04-22 RM - Save your list here2014-12-21 SV See word.

I need to count the number of occurrence of date.
the above example the count is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim strArr() As String, i As Long
Dim Comment as String
Comment = "2016-01-23 AKS Could you please check 2015-11-23 AKS Could you please check .2015-10-06 RM I added the remarks 2015-04-22 RM - Save your list here2014-12-21 SV See word."
strArr = Split(Comment, "201")
getOccuranceCount = UBound(strArr)
MsgBox getOccuranceCount
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the string to variable.

```
string test="2016-01-23 AKS Could you please check 2015-11-23 AKS Could you please check .2015-10-06 RM I added the remarks 2015-04-22 RM - Save your list here2014-12-21 SV See word.";
```

then use regex pattern for matching the dates.

pattern:`([\d]{4}[\-][\d]{2}[\-][\d]{2})`

then use `Dim regCount As New Regex(test, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`
for finding the count of matched dates.

Answer (score 0):

@BENSINGH P: Who tells you that the contained dates are all between January 1 2010 and Decembre 31 2019?

@NITHIN Vvn: The RegEx solution is cleaner but, who tells you that the date separator in the string will always be "-", and not "/" or even "."? How they are filled these strings?

@Vivek ab:
Instead of building strings (that seems to be log results), why not review your DB design and define a table with just 3 fields (an ID bounded to the parent records, a date-field and a text-field and then simply count the records per IDs with a Dcount statement?